# Show a sequence is convergent, and find it's limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that the sequence (n^2+1)/(3n^3-2n^2) for n=1,2,... is convergent and find the limit.
Can someone cofirm i've done this correctly.

(n^2+1)/(3n^3-2n^2)
dividing top and bottom by n^3 we get, (1/n +1/n^3)/(3-2/n)
As 1/n has limit 0 we get (0+0)/3-0)=0/3 = 0
So this is convergent with limit0

Thanks
Kara

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can get
an explicit upper bound
by noting that,
for $n \ge 2$,
$\dfrac{1/n +1/n^3}{3-2/n}
\le \dfrac{2/n}{3-1}
=\dfrac1{n}
$.